# WCF SOAP 1.2 service expecting SOAP 1.1 content type

Tags: wcf

I'm building a WCF web service that requires interop with non-WCF clients (in fact, there will be no WCF clients).

I've already written a WSDL using SOAP 1.2 ([as per this example](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/soap12WSDL.htm)). I've validated the WSDL and have used this file (not the WSDL generated by WCF, which is superficially different) to create a [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) test project.

I have a requirement that the web service will support SOAP 1.2, so I can't just fall back to SOAP 1.1 (which worked just fine in an early prototype).

I've used [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) to generate my WCF service, interface, and data contract classes. Everything compiles nicely and the endpoint is exposed if I hit the WCF service in my browser. All seems well with the world.

When I try to call a method from soapUi I get the following response from the server (as visible from soapUI):

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 
'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/FetchMyThing"' 
was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 08:15:29 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

(Actual method names and namespaces have been manually changed for the purposes of this question. Any typos in namespace are not errors in my code - just an oversight in typing up this question)

I know that SOAP 1.1 specifies that the content type must be **text/xml**. SOAP 1.2 requires **application/soap+xml**.

My raw request (as per soapUI):

```
POST http://localhost/MyWs.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/FetchMyThing"

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:ns="http://tempuri.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:fetchMyThingRequest attribute1="1" attribute2="10">
      </ns:fetchMyThingRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From this response, it tells me that my request is properly formed - it's a SOAP 1.2 request with the correct content type. My WCF service, however, does not expect this content type, which I assume means I have not configured it correctly and it still thinks it's a SOAP 1.1 web service.

Minimal Web.config, as per [this blog post](http://blog.allanglen.com/2010/05/implementing-a-minimal-soap-1-2-binding-in-wcf):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyNamespace.MyPort">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpSoap12" contract="IWsPort12" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="httpSoap12">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

A snippet of the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
public interface IWsPort
{
  [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/FetchMyThing")]
  [FaultContract(typeof(WsFault), Action = "http://tempuri.org/FetchMyThing", Name = "fetchMyThingFault")]
  [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
  FetchMyThingResponse FetchMyThing(FetchMyThingRequest request);
}
```

I enabled service tracing for my WCF service and see the following exception that seems to confirm my hypothesis:

```
Activity: Listen at 'http://mycomputer/MyWs.svc
<Exception>
  <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
  <Message>Content Type application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/FetchMyThing" was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.   
  </Message>
(erroneous detail snipped)
</Exception>
```

So, my contract and service bindings are probably mismatched, if this message is to believed, but from what I understand of WCF my configuration (or at least the intent behind it) is correct.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only thing I can think with it is that because you've not specified a binding in a lot of detail, and its using HTTP (as per this: "Listen at 'http://mycomputer/MyWs.svc'") then is it using the default (i.e. `basicHttpBinding`) for this, which is creating the mismatch?

Comment: Yes! This ended up being the issue - a mismatch in the name attribute specified in my .svc file (the markup) and the service name in my web.config. I was seeing runtime exceptions because my configuration was sometimes invalid - but that didn't mean it was actually being mapped to the configuration!

Comment: @StefanMohr can you tell what exactly didyou repair to make it work?

Comment: It's been over 10 years and I still remember fighting this issue! In my case, it was literally a string mismatch between the SVC declaration (where I named the service), and the service name attribute in the system.serviceModel section of web.config. I had assumed the name in web.config was just a friendly name for my own use, but it must match the name in the SVC exactly in order for it to pick up the exact service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I had multiple bindings on my service. When I removed all bindings and only left one unnamed binding in place, the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link [How to: Configure WCF Service to Interoperate with ASP.NET Web Service Clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731134(v=vs.110).aspx)
.

> To configure a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service endpoint
>   to be interoperable with ASP.NET Web service clients, use the
>   System.ServiceModel.**BasicHttpBinding** type as the binding type for your
>   service endpoint.

Also, defining two endpoints you can use HTTP and HTTPS versions of the same service