# URLConnection does not set Content-Type for SOAP 1.2

Tags: java, web-services, soap

We have a webservice client, which should be able to work with `SOAP 1.1` and `SOAP 1.2`. Currently we have the problem that the set content-type (code) is not the actual content-type (monitoring over SoapUI shows a different content-type for our request).

We use `java.net.URLConnection`

```
    private final String contentTypeSOAP12 = "application/soap+xml";

    private void createEndpoint() throws MalformedURLException {

    endpoint = new URL(new URL(webserviceConf.getUrl()), "", new URLStreamHandler() {

        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {

            URL target = new URL(url.toString());
            URLConnection connection = target.openConnection(getProxy());
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setReadTimeout(webserviceConf.getReadTimeout());
            setKeepAlive(connection);

            connection.setRequestProperty("TESTHEADER", "WERT1"); // works
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentTypeSOAP12);// does not work

            return connection;
        }
    });
}
```

By monitoring the connection over `SoapUI`, we can see that the connection header parameters are

- Content-Length   333
- User-Agent   Java/1.8.0_20
- TESTHEADER   WERT1
- Connection   close
- Content-Type text/xml; charset=utf-8
- [..]

This shows that general we are able to set parameters to the connection (see "TESTHEADER"), but for some reason our setting for the content type does not work.

While we try to set the content-type for `SOAP 1.2` our connection has the content-type for `SOAP 1.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the SOAP Framework you use is setting the Content-Type header to the SOAP 1.1 value after getting the URLConection. Hence the workaround with overriding URLStreamHandler does not work.  There should be something in the SOAP frameworks' setup that specifies that the HTTP binding for SOAP 1.2 should be used.

Maybe, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403806/wcf-soap-1-2-service-expecting-soap-1-1-content-type) helps.

Btw, which SOAP Framework is used?

Comment: We use `javax.xml.soap`.

Comment: So you use only SAAJ and no JAX-WS or Apache Axis etc.?

Comment: Yes, we only use SAAJ (`javax.xml.soap`).

Comment: Setting the content type over the SOAP Framework with `MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL)`works.